# GetFolder function fails when user doesn't browse away from default

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using this code snippet to allow a user to browse for a folder where to save a file. The problem occurs when the user doesn't browse to other folders (so he wants to save into the default folder).

So when a user runs this code and immediately clicks OK, I get this error:

> Test KIT exchange
>
> Path does not exist

[image: error message example]

```
Function GetFolder(Optional strPath As String) As String
          
    Dim fldr As Object   
    Dim sItem As String   
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(4)   
          
    With fldr   
       .Title = "Select a Folder"   
       .AllowMultiSelect = False   
       If strPath <> "" Then   
          .InitialFileName = strPath   
       End If   
       If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode   
           sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With   
         
    NextCode:   
    GetFolder = sItem   
    Set fldr = Nothing   
       
End Function
```

If the user browses to the parent folder and then back to the default folder, it runs as expected.

What could be the cause here?

Comment: `.Show` returns a `Boolean` ...why coerce it into an integer type and compare it to `-1` instead of just `If Not .Show Then GoTo NextCode`?

Answer (score 1):

`If strPath = "D:\Folder"` shows the correct folder, but fails when you click OK.

`If strPath = "D:\Folder\"` runs fine.

Though the output is again D:\Folder, which is kinda odd if you ask me...

Answer (score 0):

Since the [`FileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog) object may be used for either a folder or file selection depending on the [`DialogType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.dialogtype) argument supplied, if you omit the trailing path delimiter from the [`InitialFilename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.initialfilename) property, the supplied value will be interpreted as a filename with the edit box populated with the name of the 'file'.